# VB/C# - Convert Date.Now time format to Military Time

Tags: c#, vb.net, date, date-format

I have to use a `Date` type variable which i will use in query. 
I have declared the variable as below:

```
Public Shared _endDate As Date? = Date.Now
```

And the format time for the `_endDate` is `7/29/2016 2:01:51 PM`, but in my queries the Date is in this format `2016-07-01 14:35:56.000`.
How can i convert the `_endDate` value to this (`2016-07-01 14:35:56.000`) format?

Solutions in `C#` or `VB` would be helpful.

Comment: A date is a date.  It's just a number in the computer.  How you *display* it depends on where you're trying to display it when you convert it to a string for display.  So, where are you seeing it in each of those formats?

Comment: You can format the value any way you like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Your sql query should be using a date, not a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ToString`:

```
Dim militaryTime As String = ""
If _endDate.HasValue Then militaryTime = _endDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
string endDateString = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!